# Automatically execute a command when move to a specific directory?

Tags: unix

As AUTOGEN.EXE that execute commands when USB drive plugged in the WINDOWS, is there any way to execute a command when move to specific directory in UNIX based OS?

For example, when I hit `cd ~/mydir` than execute some command like `echo "Welcome to mydir!"`.

Comment: What do you mean by changing a directory? Add a file or subdirectory, remove a file or subdirectory, change the name, perform a `touch`, ...?

Comment: I just meant to move to some directory.

Comment: I guess you could define a custom `cd` function that does whatever you want (and then calls the real `cd`).

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21363/execute-bash-scripts-on-entering-a-directory

Comment: That's nice! Thank you for your helpful answer!!